# JOptionpane.showMessageDialog not working inside of if-statement (event handler Program)

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jframe, joptionpane

**Context**

I'm trying to build a **percentage calculator** using **JFrame** and **event handling** by having blank text fields and "enter" buttons and displaying the answer depending on which button they click (two different calculations for each button).

**Problem**

Thing is, when I put the JOptionPane.showMessageDialog line inside of the if/else if statement (all in the actionPerformed method), the program runs, but **clicking the buttons does nothing**. But if I put it outside of the statements, it says the **answer variable is undeclared**.

I realize a percentage calculator can be done in a million other, simpler ways, but this is simply what I had in mind and wanted to see if I could do it (I'm a complete beginner).

**Code**

```
public class PercentageCalc extends JFrame{
private JTextField item2, item4, item5, item7;
private JButton button, button2;

public PercentageCalc(){
    super("Percentage Calculator");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JLabel item1 = new JLabel("What is");
    add(item1);

    JTextField item2 = new JTextField(3);
    add(item2);

    JLabel item3 = new JLabel("% of");
    add(item3);

    JTextField item4 = new JTextField(2);
    add(item4);
    button = new JButton("Enter");
    add(button);
    JLabel spacer = new JLabel("                       ");
    add(spacer);

    JTextField item5 = new JTextField(3);
    add(item5);

    JLabel item6 = new JLabel("is what % of");
    add(item6);

    JTextField item7 = new JTextField(3);
    add(item7);
    button2 = new JButton("Enter");
    add(button2);


    thehandler handler = new thehandler();
    button.addActionListener(handler);
    button2.addActionListener(handler); 
}
private class thehandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String strx;
        String stry;
        double x, y, answer;
        if(e.getSource()==button){
            strx = item2.getText();
            stry = item4.getText();
            x = Double.parseDouble(strx);
            y = Double.parseDouble(stry);
            answer = y * 0.01 * x;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, answer);
        }
            else if(e.getSource()==button2){
            strx = item5.getText();
            stry = item7.getText();
            x = Double.parseDouble(strx);
            y = Double.parseDouble(stry);
            answer = x/y*100;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, answer);
            }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have member-variable and local variable with the same name. Please read [ere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297180/what-are-shadow-variables-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092099/what-is-variable-shadowing-used-for-in-a-java-class) about it.

Here is the corrected variant of you program

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class PrecentageCalc extends JFrame {
    private JTextField item2, item4, item5, item7;

    private JButton button, button2;

    public PrecentageCalc() {
        super("Percentage Calculator");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel item1 = new JLabel("What is");
        add(item1);

        item2 = new JTextField(3);
        add(item2);

        JLabel item3 = new JLabel("% of");
        add(item3);

        item4 = new JTextField(2);
        add(item4);
        button = new JButton("Enter");
        add(button);
        JLabel spacer = new JLabel("                       ");
        add(spacer);

        item5 = new JTextField(3);
        add(item5);

        JLabel item6 = new JLabel("is what % of");
        add(item6);

        item7 = new JTextField(3);
        add(item7);
        button2 = new JButton("Enter");
        add(button2);

        thehandler handler = new thehandler();
        button.addActionListener(handler);
        button2.addActionListener(handler);
    }

    private class thehandler implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String strx;
            String stry;
            double x, y, answer;
            if (e.getSource() == button) {
                strx = item2.getText();
                stry = item4.getText();
                x = Double.parseDouble(strx);
                y = Double.parseDouble(stry);
                answer = y * 0.01 * x;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, answer);
            } else if (e.getSource() == button2) {
                strx = item5.getText();
                stry = item7.getText();
                x = Double.parseDouble(strx);
                y = Double.parseDouble(stry);
                answer = x / y * 100;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, answer);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frm = new PrecentageCalc();
        frm.pack();
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Making these changes causes the error: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException` to appear when I click the button (although the Program still compiles and runs).

Comment: I just edited the original post and posted the entire code (minus the imported stuff and the main method, which isn't really relevant).

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help :) Also, thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0):

Use separate ActionListeners for your buttons. Both use the same calculation method with different parameters:

```
public PercentageCalc() { 

  // Part of your code   

  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      handleInput(item2.getText(), item4.getText());
    }
  });

  button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      handleInput(item5.getText(), item7.getText());
    }
  });

}

private void handleInput(final String strx, final String stry) {
  final double x = Double.parseDouble(strx);
  final double y = Double.parseDouble(stry);
  final double answer = y * 0.01 * x;
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, answer);
}
```