# Random boolean is always false

Tags: java

Whenever i create a goblin object and call the method isNice, it always return false. But when i do System.out.println(nice) it does it randomly.

```
public class Goblin
{

    private boolean nice;
    private boolean isNice;


    public Goblin()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
          Random rand = new Random();
         boolean nice = rand.nextBoolean();

    }

    public boolean isNice()
    {

            return true;

        else 
            return false;
    }
```

}

Comment: First, just return the boolean: `isNice() { return isNice; }`

Comment: Because you don't assign the result of `rand.nextBoolean()` to `nice` but to a local variable.

Comment: You are setting a local variable instead of a class property. As a solution try `this.nice = rand.nextBoolean();`

Comment: `isNice` can be simplified to `return nice;`.

Comment: The `boolean nice` in the constructor declares a *local variable* that is **shadowing** the *field* `nice`, so you're not setting the value of the field anywhere. See [What are Shadow Variables in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26297180/5221149)

Comment: Maybe, you output isNice variable (which by default initialized to false), not isNice() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
boolean nice = rand.nextBoolean();
```

is declaring and assigning a local variable. You aren't assigning the field, so it will always have its default value, `false`, when you access it with the getter.

Drop the `boolean`.

Comment: To explain further: Since you didn't assign `nice` to true- `nice` will never equal true and thus the method `isNice()` always returns false.